# Using QWER keys to jump to a specific scene in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, scene

**TLDR: I need code in action script 3 which will let users press keys like QWER to jump to a specific scene.**

So what I'm doing is creating and interactive comic within flash, and to be blunt I didn't know any AS3 code before this and still pretty much know none.

So I'm going to need some help on this one and I think it is worth mentioning that I am using sound in this project.

what I need to know is how to use letter keys (eg. QWER) to act as shorts cuts to jump to specific scenes. What I have so far which is working is this and another version which uses a mouse click instead.

```
stop(); ( 1 ) 


stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_KeyboardDownHandler);


function fl_KeyboardDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {



          gotoAndPlay(currentFrame+1);

}
```

and of course all this does is advance the frame, which I do need for some sections of dialogue but that's the basis I've been trying to get it to work.

I do know that  q = 81, w = 87, e = 69 and r = 82.

Besides that I've got nothing and I need some help real bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check which key has been pressed, you can do it like this:

```
function fl_KeyboardDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
 if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.Q){
     //do what you need to do when Q was pressed
 }else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.W){
     //same for W
 }

 ...etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The *KeyboardEvent* instance contains data about the event itself, part of it being **keyCode**, which gives the code of the pressed key. Using this property, you can detect which key the user pressed, and react accordingly.

As you understood, you can use *gotoAndPlay()* and *gotoAndStop()* to move around your animation.

It gives us the following code :

```
stop();
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_KeyboardDownHandler);

function fl_KeyboardDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
  if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.Q) {
    gotoAndPlay(1); // Back to the start
  } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W) {
    gotoAndPlay(currentFrame-1); // Back one frame
  } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.E) {
    gotoAndPlay(currentFrame-1); // Forward one frame
  } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.R) {
    gotoAndPlay(100); // Go to 100th frame
  }
}
```

Note that I am using the *Keyboard* class to get the keyCode associated to a specific key.

Comment: Minor note, you cannot use (event.keyCode = Keyboard.whatever) it has to be (event.keyCode == Keyboard.whatever). NEVER mix up your == with =

Comment: @DodgerThud Duh. I replied to quickly, and didn't took the time to reread my code. Fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Hey thanks for that It's pretty much exactly what I wanted, however can you tell me how to get it to gotoAndPlay to a specific scene? also what to do if said scene has a custom name?

Comment: gotoAndPlay() has an optional 2nd parameter to indicate the scene you want to go to. So You'll just hav to use : gotoAndPlay(1, "myScene");